# Sort DataGridView cells in programmatic way

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, programming-languages, datagridview

I have a datagridview called DGV, and I'm trying to use the sort function to sort the first cell in a programmatic way using :

```
DGV.Sort(Rang, System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending);
```

but on output I have this :

1, 10, 100, 11, 12, ..., 19, 2, 20, 21, ...

I have already set the SortMode of Rang cell to Programmatic, but I have always this output.

What's the problem ? !

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears to be sorting based on *place* value, which is how a `string` datatype would be sorted. You need to make sure that the column you sort on is an `int`.

Edit:
If you are going to attempt to parse your string value, I recommend using the `TryParse( )` method. Here is an example of what your Comparer *might* look like:

```
    int Compare ( object obj1, object obj2  )
    {
        IComparer _comparer = Comparer.Default;
        int val1, val2;

        if (!Int32.TryParse ( obj1.ToString ( ), out val1 ))
            return -1;

        if (!Int32.TryParse ( obj2.ToString ( ), out val2 ))
            return -1;

        return _comparer.Compare ( val1, val2 );
    }
```

Comment: Yes, they are string bucause I'm adding them from a file using DGV.Rows.Add(words[0]); which I get them from 

text = sInputLine;
                string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);

Comment: @dotNet: well, then you are getting the correct results. If you want the DGV to sort numerically, then you need to compare int to int.

Comment: Yes true thanks, I should do DGV.Rows.Add(int.Parse(words[0]));